# is it possible to find other column using a column in mysql using row value?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

for example my database includes 4 columns post_id, post_title,post_tag and post_story. is it possible to find post_tag using post_title?

Comment: Which result do you want?  "post_title"?

Comment: This question makes no sense whatsoever.  All rows have the same columns in a relational database.

Comment: oh yes ,sorry it made no sense indeed. i was trying to find value of post_tag using post_title. i am kinda dumb sorry.

Comment: `SELECT post_tag FROM myTable WHERE post_title=?`

Comment: yes, thats what i wanted . thanks